# Add tag to xml without changing other tags javax.xml

Tags: xml

I try tag in XML, it's added but other tags change value.

Example : Source xml

```
    <G_31>
      <NAME Pref="1-">water , alalal &#10;xxxx, xxxxx 9420xx, xxxx.xxxx. 2376xxx (xxx xxxxxx &#10;x xxxxxxx 2324.79xx): &#13;&#10;</NAME>
      <FIRMA Pref="xxxxxx.:"> xxxx xxxxx, x.x., xxxx xxxxx x.x. </FIRMA>
      <TM Pref="(ТМ)">  xxxxx&#13;&#10;</TM>
      <PL Pref="2-"></PL>
      <PLACE>6 </PLACE>
      <PLACE2>(1-xxxxx xxxxx), xx-785, xx 6 xxxxxxxxx/PX&#13;&#10;</PLACE2>
      <TARA Pref="2.1-">xx</TARA>
    </G_31>
```

After transform :

```
<G_31>
      <NAME Pref="1-">xxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx xxxxxx 
xxxxxxx, xxxxx 2376xxx (xxx xxxx x xxxx 2324.79xx): 
</NAME>
      <FIRMA Pref="xxxxx.:"> xxxx xxxxx, x.x. </FIRMA>
      <TM Pref="(ТМ)">  xxxxx&#13;
</TM>
      <PL Pref="2-"/>
      <PLACE>1</PLACE>
      <PLACE2>, xx-785, xx 6 xxxx/PX&#13;
</PLACE2>
      <TARA Pref="2.1-">xxx</TARA>
    </G_31>
```

I use this code (javax.xml):

```
        public void changeXML(String fileName) {
            File xmlFile = new File(filename);
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            try {
                builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                addElement(doc);

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "cp1251");
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                String strResult = writer.toString();
                System.out.println(strResult);
               // addFileInAltaLoader(strResult, fileName.replaceAll("/", "_"));
                System.out.println("XML changed!");

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But it's code deleted all (&# 10;) and add \r\n
How i can add one tag in xml without change other?

Comment: Zeo, It is better to take another approach. I would suggest XSLT transformation.

Comment: You say about XSD schema?